# Remove the Last Line of RichTextBox WPF

Tags: wpf, line, richtextbox

I need to delete the last line of RichTextBox in WPF, to remove the item

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to remove from the screenshot and add any relevant code.

Comment: If you have solved it, put your solution in the answer box provided. Do not put in in a comment and add the word "(Solved)" the title. Problems are marked as solved on Stack Overflow by having an answer that has been accepted - and then you will get reputation points, as described in the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

A RichTextBox doesn't work on a line-by-line basis, but on flow content.

To quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Specifically, the content edited in a RichTextBox is flow content.
>   Flow content can contain many types of elements including formatted
>   text, images, lists, and tables. See Flow Document Overview for in
>   depth information on flow documents. In order to contain flow content,
>   a RichTextBox hosts a FlowDocument object which in turn contains the
>   editable content.

But, to get and manipulate content, I'd suggest taking a look at some of the examples at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754030%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something there should fit what you're dealing with.

Comment: I solved my problem with the following code: myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(MyRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.LastBlock);                                                                                            thank you all

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on Aaron Thomas' answer, the problem was solved with the following code:

```c#
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(myRichTextBox.Document.‌​Blocks.LastBlock);
```